# ContextMenu CanExecute is not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, mvvm-light, icommand

I have a problem regarding the state of a menuitem in ContextMenu. I have a ObversableCollection of Cars. The cars are visualized in a ListBox, for each ListBox Item I want a ContextMenu. In that ContextMenu there is an option ReserveCar.

They problem I'm having is that the `CanExecute` of the `Car` is only executed once when I right click any car. They `CanExecute` will not be called anymore after that when I right click an other `Car`.

This causes that when I rightclick a `Car` which can be Reserved, the `MenuItem` is active, but when I then rightclick another which I should not be able to reserve the `MenuItem` remains active (because `CanExecute` is not called again).

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Reserve Car" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"
                        Command="{Binding ReserveCarCommand}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="{StaticResource ReserveCarIcon}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

My ViewModel:

```
private RelayCommand<Car> _reserveCarCommand;
public ICommand ReserveCarCommand
{
    get { return _reserveCarCommand ?? (_reserveCarCommand = new RelayCommanReserveCar, CanReserveCar)); }
}

public bool CanReserveCar(Car car)
{
    return !car.IsReserved && ReservationsAreOpen;
}

public void ReserveCar(Car car)
{
    car.IsReserved = true;
}
```

Also when I manually refresh the Command when doing something, the `CanExecute` is called with a `null` as parameter, so thats not working either.

```
if (_reserveCarCommand != null) _reserveCarCommand .RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the context menu on `ListBoxItem` instead of `ListBox`. As binding of context menu for `ListBox` happen only at the fist right click so `CanExectute` will not fire after first right click.

```
<ListBox Name="simpleListBox"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        ...
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```